# Thymeleaf - construct url without string concatination

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

**As I am using distributed services I need this format:** `baseUrl/path`. **So using the variable as parameter will not work out.**

I got the following code:

```
@GetMapping(HOME)
public String showHomeView(@PathVariable Integer cartId, Model model){
    Integer customerId = cartRequestComponent.getCustomerIdByCartId(cartId);
    Customer customer = getCustomerById(customerId);
    model.addAttribute("articleServiceBaseUrl", articleServiceBaseUrl);
    return "home";
}
```

And the href:

```
<a th:href="${articleServiceBaseUrl}/article/addArticle">Add article</a>
```

Also tried:

```
<a th:href="${articleServiceBaseUrl}+/article/addArticle">Add article</a>
```

And:

```
<a th:href="__${articleServiceBaseUrl}__/article/addArticle">Add article</a>
```

And:

```
<a th:href="__${articleServiceBaseUrl}__+/article/addArticle">Add article</a>
```

**This works but I prefer not to use as I got longer urls few more variables**

```
<a th:href="${articleServiceBaseUrl}+'/article/addArticle'">Add article</a>
```

For others this works pretty fine:

```
/customer/home/__${cart.cartId}__">home</a>
```

**How can I inject variables without using `'`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [literal substitution](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions), so you don't have to use quotes.  If you do that, your expression will look like this:

```
<a th:href="|${articleServiceBaseUrl}/article/addArticle|">Add article</a>
```

or

```
|/customer/home/${cart.cartId}|
```

That being said, the standard url expressions should be used in most cases.

```
|/customer/home/${cart.cartId}|
```

could be represented as

```
@{/customer/home/{cart}(cart=${cart.cartId})}
```

`@{...}` expressions do support links to other servers/hosts, but if you do that they must begin with `http://` or `https://`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the @ annotation it helps a lot case use for example :
Client Home
Hope that this answer respond to your question

Comment: I want to reach another service which has another host. When I use '@' I get the short path of my own service.